# What compensation am I entitled to for a delay in a flight from HND to MAD with a step over in FCO?

Tags: europe, eu, compensation, delays

I recently flew from HND to MAD in two flights, one from HND to FCO (which was not delayed) and another one from FCO to MAD (which was cancelled and the airline provided an alternative flight the next day, over 10 hours later). I purchased both flights bundled together as a trip from Tokyo to Madrid. The airline is Ita Airways. I'm a EU citizen currently living outside the EU (in Switzerland). As far as I know, the delay was not caused by extraordinary circumstances (the reason for the delay was not specified in the email I received). What compensation am I entitled to?

After reading https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#compensation-delay-1 my understanding is that the carrier should compensate me with 600 EUR since:

1. The delay at arrival was well over 3 hours
2. The distance between HND and MAD is far greater than 3500 km
3. The destination (Madrid) is in the EU
4. The carrier is an EU airline (Ita Airways)

However I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting my rights and I'm only entitled to 250 EUR because the flight from HND to FCO was not delayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my understanding is that the carrier should compensate me with 600 EUR

Correct. The compensation is based on your complete itinerary, not on a single leg.

File the claim with ITA and see what happens. It's unfortunately VERY common that the airline will simply ignore your claim or push back with some bogus excuse. If that happens, you will need to follow up frequently and push back.